# Reorder a pandas data frame based off a list with duplicated values

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe in the following form:

```
    company  col1     col2   col3
    name
 0  A             0    130      0
 1  C           173      0      0
 2  Z             0      0    150
 3  A             0    145      0
 4  Z             0      0    140
 5  Z             0      0    110
```

And I would like to reorder the dataframe based on the following list:

```
list=['A', 'Z', 'Z', 'A', 'C', 'Z']
```

I can't set 'company name' as the index and the use `df.reindex(list)` as I have duplicate entries in that index. It's crucial that I have duplicate entries (the data is dummy data).

How do I reorder a df in this case?

Comment: which 'Z' should be on second position? there are 3 Zs

Comment: @cph_sto the one with the highest number in its column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with helper `DataFrame` created with list and counter column by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

*Notice:*
*Dont use variable name `list`, because python code word.*

```
L = ['A', 'Z', 'Z', 'A', 'C', 'Z']

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'company':L})
df1['g'] = df1.groupby('company').cumcount()
df['g'] = df.groupby('company').cumcount()

df = df1.merge(df)
print (df)
  company  g  col1  col2  col3
0       A  0     0   130     0
1       Z  0     0     0   150
2       Z  1     0     0   140
3       A  1     0   145     0
4       C  0   173     0     0
5       Z  2     0     0   110
```